# How to get a valid integer input but allows null input from user?

Tags: input, null, integer

I want to repeatedly ask a user to input an integer, but also allow them to cancel. I have this:

```
int numSelectedCols = 0;
boolean validInput = false;

while(!(numSelectedCols > 0) && !validInput) {
    try {
        numSelectedCols = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of columns to be selected: "));
        validInput = true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer value");
    }
}
```

It repeatedly asks for a valid input but when I press the 'cancel' button, it still keeps asking. How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works:

```
    while(!validInput) {
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of columns to be selected: ");
    if(input != null) {
        try {
            numSelectedCols = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if(numSelectedCols > 0) {
                validInput = true;
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer value");
        }
    }
    else {
        validInput = true;
    }
}
```